# nag l2tabu caption/label checking versus \subcaptionbox

Tags: warnings, subcaption, nag

The [`nag`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nag) package used with the `l2tabu` option complains when `\label` is used in a float without following a `\caption`.  Unfortunately, it does not understand that the first argument of `\subcaptionbox` from the [`subcaption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package *is* a caption.  It therefore complains here when it should not:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{Subfigure caption\label{example}}{subfigure content}
  \caption{Main figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Sample output:

```
Package nag Warning: \label in float, but not after \caption on input line 7.
```

(Warning repeats four times.)

Any suggestions on how I can teach `nag` that `\subcaptionbox` creates a caption, and therefore that `\label` should be allowed here?

Comment: What about just ignoring the nag? :-)

Comment: Unfortunately my coauthors tend to ignore _all_ nags, including important ones, unless I put `nag` in `abort` mode.  And if I do that, then ignoring these nags is no longer an option.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One could use this very dirty hack to satisfy the nag package:

```
\RequirePackage[l2tabu]{nag}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\makeatletter
\let\subcaptionboxORI\subcaptionbox
\renewcommand\subcaptionbox{%
  \csname nag@hascaptiontrue\endcsname
  \subcaptionboxORI}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \subcaptionbox{Subfigure caption\label{example}}{subfigure content}
  \caption{Main figure caption}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately this has an unwanted side-effect: The internal flag of the `nag` package will now be set by `\subcaptionbox*`, which does not create a reference for `\label`, too. This is wrong.

So a better solution is updating to version 3.3 of the `caption` package. This version is available now and it contains an adaption to the `nag` package.

Comment: I'll have to doublecheck, I vaguely recall defining `\nag@captionprovider` and `\nag@labelprovider` for that purpose. But you're correct, it won't distinguish the starred form.

Comment: @Ulrich: As soon as I have a solution I would like to send it to you for revision before uploading it to CTAN, is this ok? Furthermore I would like to solve the issue mentioned in section 4.1 of the nag doc.

Comment: Sure. (He said, without checking what the problem of section 4.1 was :D )

Comment: Since I'm just about fixing another bug (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/38523/are-subcaption-and-tabularx-incompatible ) the `nag` adaption will take some more time. Please hold the line...

Comment: I'm deeply sorry for the long delay but finally v3.3 of the `caption` package which fixes this is available now. (Will edit my answer right now...)