# Are subcaption and tabularx incompatible?

Tags: incompatibility, tabularx, subcaption, debugging

I know that tex.sx isn't the forum for bug-reporting, but I have a bit of a problem and I'm looking for a technical workaround.  The following MWE produces odd labels:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure*}
  \begin{subfigure}{0.3\textwidth}
    Figure 1a
    \caption{Fig1a}
    \label{fig:1a}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
\begin{tabularx}{0.5\textwidth}{r}
Figure 1b
\end{tabularx}
    \caption{Fig1b}
    \label{fig:1b}
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{Fig1}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure*}
\begin{figure}
Figure 2
\caption{Fig2 caption}
\label{fig:2}
\end{figure}
Figures \ref{fig:1a}, \ref{fig:1b}, and \ref{fig:1} should be 1a, 1b
and 1; Figure \ref{fig:2} should be 2.
\end{document}
```

Specifically, the last line of text reads, "Figures 1a, 1b, and **2** should be 1a, 1b and **1**; Figure **3** should be **2**."  (I know that the example doesn't use any of `tabularx`'s features; merely the use of the `tabularx` environment is enough to throw off the labels.)  If I move the `\caption{Fig1}\label{fig:1}` above the subfigures, then I get the right numbering, but of course the caption is now in the wrong position.

According to `\listfiles`, I'm using

```
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h 
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h 
subcaption.sty    2011/10/30 v1.1c 
 caption.sty    2011/11/10 v3.2e 
caption3.sty    2011/11/01 v1.4a 
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 
tabularx.sty    1999/01/07 v2.07 
   array.sty    2008/09/09 v2.4c
```

So my question is, what is `tabularx` doing that is not properly respecting the label counter, and how could I have deduced that myself?

Comment: Not sure if this constitutes an answer, but if you change `tabularx` to `tabular*` then everything seems to work the way you want

Comment: This is clearly a bug in my `subcaption` package (I can't explain yet). I will take a closer look at it tomorrow, and try to offer a fix ASAP.

Comment: @cmhughes, In the non-minimal document from which this derived, I need to use `tabularx`'s formatting abilities, rather than just controlling the width of the table via `tabular*`.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt The problem is in line 68 of `tabularx.sty`, where, according to the documentation, all values of counters are saved *globally* while, as I understand, `subcaption` steps `figure` only locally inside a `subfigure` environment.

Comment: I will build a new version 3.2f of my caption package on this week-end anyway, so I will include a fix for that one, too, and it should be available within the next days.

Comment: Just a short note that I haven't forgotten this issue. I already have re-written the sub-caption and continued-float support so no local counters are used anymore (which unfortunately was much more work than initially estimated), and at least the above MWE is working fine now. But this fundamental change also needs some adaptions to the `sidecap` and `fltpage` package support, and this is what I'm currently working on. So please hold the line...

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt, any news?  I just tried again with the latest update through MikTeX (version 3.2f of caption.sty and 1.1d of subcaption.sty), and the MWE still doesn't work for me...

Comment: I did not found any time to carry on with v3.3 in the last weeks, therefore I decided to backport at least the straight-ahead bugfixes from v3.3 to v3.2f since some people have waited for this. (Therefore 3.2f will not fix this issue.) I hope I can release v3.3 (which fixes this issue) on Easter, but since I have a full-time job, a wife, and four cats I cannot promise anything.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt, no worries.  It's not urgent; just keeping an eye on it :)

Comment: Finally I found some time during my holidays to finish v3.3 (where I had to rewrite much more code than estimated) and it is on it's way to CTAN right now. I'm deeply sorry for the long delay.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the fact that `subfigure` steps the `figure` counter, in order to assign correctly the meaning to the `\label` commands inside it. However it does it only locally, so that the main `\caption` command will assign the correct figure number.

However, part of `tabularx` working is to save *globally* the value of all counters (this is because it processes twice its contents and counters need to be restored to their previous values)

A workaround seems issuing `\addtocounter{figure}{-1}` before the main `\caption`, after a `subfigure` environment containing `tabularx`.

**Update 2013/01/09 (from Axel Sommerfeldt):**

The (now available) version 3.3 of the `caption` package has a different counter handling, so counters will now neither be changed locally, nor decremented temporarily anymore. This will hopefully fix all issues regarding wrong figure or table counters, so updating the `caption` package should help.

Comment: Thanks!  That workaround does indeed resolve my bug, but I'm going to hold off accepting this answer for a bit to give Axel a chance to address it properly in his package.  Also, (and this just being slightly cheeky),  the question was intended not just as a fix-my-bug question, but did ask, "how might I have diagnosed that myself?"... :)  I can read through LaTeX code reasonably well, but I'm not familiar with the guts of either of these packages.  Did you do anything particularly clever to find this global save, or just "read through the code"?

Comment: The problem is that the figure number is off by 1; so I put some `\showthe\value{figure}` around to figure out where it was changed. Then I read `tabularx` code commentary and found out what possibly is the cause.

Comment: @egreg: Thanks for the analysis. I'm unhappy with this workaround since it will have a negative effect ones the problem was fixed. But I must confess that I can't offer a better one, therefore I just upvoted your answer.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Just remember me when the package is fixed, or edit the answer yourself to tell everybody that the workaround has become obsolete. I'm sure that Ben will keep an eye on his question. Moreover, people finding this with search engines will see the updated answer.

Comment: @egreg I just updated your answer, hope it's ok.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Of course you did right! `:-)`